# How to make a web application run as fast as when I run it directly through the server?

Tags: wireless, performance

I have a web application that run from a local server. When I run the application from the server using remote desktop connection, the application performance is smooth and fast. For example, searching for data or opening windows takes only around a second.

But when I run the application from my computer, the application performance is very slow, and searching for a data record can take a half minute instead of a second.

What is the reason of the slowness of the application performance? Is it the application itself or the network speed?

How to make the application run faster in my computer in the same speed, when I run it directly from the server?

Comment: You are not giving us enough information. What does the network look like, what are the network device models and configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that it is the Network Engineering SE, I explain only the network related part.

You can very easily decide, if it is an (on-topic) network related problem, or an (off-topic) problem in your web application: test your network on layer 1, 2 and 3.

It actually means:

1. test your network connectivity, maybe there is a packet loss. You can do this very easily with ping (instead of some builtin tool, I would suggest to use rather a dedicated tester tool). If there isn't too big packet loss, you can this close out.
2. simply *measure* the total loaded data in a typical working session. There are various tools also for this, most simplest is maybe the cross-platform [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).
3. *measure* your actual bandwidth to the server, the simplest way for that is to simply download a big file from it.

Furthermore, if it is an application-level problem, it can be still network related. For example, it is possible that your web-app (or its server side container) tries to resolve your IP address by a reverse DNS lookup, and it timeouts in the lack of a properly configured reverse DNS service.